# MediaRecorder Video recording : Noisy image

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am sending this message because I'm facing an issue when recording a video using an Android tablet (iMX53 on Android 2.3.3).

At first, here is the result :

[image]

Note : The Green part and the blue part depends on what I record.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
  public boolean startRecording(){


    try {
        camera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(320,240);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000);

        String uniqueOutFile =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/test.3gp";
        File outFile = new File(uniqueOutFile);
        if (outFile.exists()) {
            outFile.delete();
        }
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(uniqueOutFile);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
        started = true;
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        camera.lock();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        camera.lock();
    return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
```

Does anyone as a clue on what can create this ? Do you know another way ? Advices... ?

Thank you by advance.

Regards,

Comment: Try to change output format and increase video size

Comment: I tried MP4 but the size of my file is always 0bytes.

Comment: Check in device . 0bytes in device when you set MP4 ?

Comment: Sorry, if it wasn"t cleared. 
No data are saved in the file when I used OutputFormat.MPEG_4

Comment: Have you check in device ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the way I can do it. I used OutputFormat.Default to try. Same result as MP4.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25219/discussion-between-nirav-ranpara-and-joze)